# Render HTML entities inside a string in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-entities

I'm facing issue while displaying curly quotes HTML entities in React JS. Ref [straight and curly quotes](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)

```
    render() {
      return (
              <h4>
              {theme == 'blue' && 'This is sample text'}
              {theme == 'red' && 'What&rsquo;s your role in this project'}
              </h4>
            )
         }
```

**Current Output**

```
What&rsquo;s your role in this project
```

**Expected Output** 
What’s your role in this project 
 
I don't want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML or i don't want to define these values in react state property. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not use `"` instead of `'` ? That way you can avoid using template strings also no?
Essentially `"What's your role in this project"`

Comment: There is a difference between ' and ’ (curly quote). and we don't have that in keyboard need to get via html entities @ShyamPillai   ref - https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `String.fromCharCode` method:

Check React docs : https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

To Find the char code: http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html

```
render() {
          return (
                  <h4>
                  {theme == 'blue' && 'This is sample text'}
                  {theme == 'red' && `What ${String.fromCharCode(8217}s your role in this project`}
                  </h4>
                )
             }
```

template literals `` for the text

```
render() {
          return (
                  <h4>
                  {theme == 'blue' && 'This is sample text'}
                  {theme == 'red' && `What’s your role in this project`}
                  </h4>
                )
             }
```

Using double quotes and single quotes

```
render() {
          return (
                  <h4>
                  {theme == 'blue' && 'This is sample text'}
                  {theme == 'red' && "What’s your role in this project"}
                  </h4>
                )
             }
```

Use escape character

```
 return (
                  <h4>
                  {theme == 'blue' && 'This is sample text'}
                  {theme == 'red' && 'What \’s your role in this project'}
                  </h4>
                )
             }
```

Comment: There is a difference between ' and ’ (curly quote). and we don't have that in keyboard need to get via html entities. https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html

Comment: @PraveenMP I updated the solution a little bit. Does that help you ?

Comment: @PraveenMP please check the solution and react docs: https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't use `"` or template strings, try returning a fragment

```
<>What&rsquo;s your role in this project</>
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the easiest way to achieve this using React **Fragment** tag

```
     render() {
      return (
              <h4>
              {theme == 'blue' && 'This is sample text'}
              {theme == 'red' && <Fragment>What&rsquo;s your role in this project</Fragment>}
              </h4>
            )
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use template string `What's your role in this project`.

Comment: I tried that, That doesn't work in all the browsers.